# Add UserClaim with Identity asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

In my class I call `ApplicationRole` and `ApplicationUser` as:

```
private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
public Guid UserId { get; set; }

public AssignRoleToUserModel(
    RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager,
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _roleManager = roleManager;
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

And I have a method to assign roles to users like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(RoleToUserModel model)
{
    var roleId = model.RoleId.ToString();
    var userId = model.UserId.ToString();
    var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
    var roleName = role.Name;
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);
    return  RedirectToPage();
}
```

So in other words. I add new register to `UserRole` table with this

```
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);
```

My question is, what is the method to add new register to `UserClaim` table? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost everything, you only need a claim you are going to assign to the user.

```
await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user,claim)
```